# jquery $.each or javascript for loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, each

i'm a javascript, jquery newbie :)
how can i make a loop here on all the href within #rfr-topnav using javascript or jquery?
thanks in advance.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
        var sel="#rfr-topnav a[href*='#root#']";
        var href=$(sel).attr('href');
        var rootUrl = $('#ctl00_RootUrlId').attr('value');
        var newhref=rootUrl+href.substr(href.indexOf('#root#')+6);
        $(sel).attr ('href',newhref);
});
</script>
```

Comment: Can you explain a bit more about the requirement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refactoring slightly, I think this is what you want:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var $sel = $("#rfr-topnav a[href*='#root#']");
    var rootUrl = $('#ctl00_RootUrlId').val();

    $sel.each(function() {
        var $this = $(this), href = $this.attr('href');
        $this.attr('href', rootUrl + href.slice(href.indexOf('#root#') + 6));
    });
});
```

Comment: with the same how could i change a url from http://abc.com/radiofr/my/Person.aspx?accountname=radiofr\Administrateur
to
http://abc.com/radiofr/intranet/_layouts/rf.portal.web/person.aspx?accountname=radiofr\Administrateur

Comment: use the string replace function

Comment: hmmm back after a while...i have just noticed that this script doesn't work in IE 7 or 8 but it works in firefox!

Comment: @user472285: In what way does it not work? Any error messages? A test page we can see?