# jquery change replace url

Tags: jquery, replace

with the same principle than [this script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4656973/jquery-each-or-javascript-for-loop), how could i change a url

from

http://abc.com/radiofr/my/Person.aspx?accountname=radiofr\Administrateur

to

http://abc.com/radiofr/intranet/_layouts/rf.portal.web/person.aspx?accountname=radiofr\Administrateur

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why not just replace the /my/

```
var s='http://abc.com/radiofr/my/Person.aspx?accountname=radiofr\Administrateur';

alert(s.replace(/\/my\//,'intranet/_layouts/rf.portal.web/'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply get the pathname using plain old javascript location
If you want to get just the last part you can use location.pathname 
replace the bit required

```
var href = location.href;
href.replace("radiofr/my", "radiofr/intranet/_layouts/rf.portal.web");
```

Note : grabbed the url with javascript as not entirely sure what the purpose of this action is and whether the url is a known string at that point